# String comparison in Bash for loop ignored

Tags: bash

I am trying to rename some files, with the information of other files with the same name but other ending. The string comparison within the for loops is completely ignored. No matter if I use ==, which should give me the desired result or !=, which should return nothing. Here is an example script:

```
for file in *.bz2; do
fullname="$file"
extension="${fullname#*.}"
filename="${fullname%.out.*}"
    for tfile in *.txt; do
        tfullname="$tfile"
        tfilename="${tfullname%.*}"
        if [ $filename==$tfilename ]; then # this satement is ignored, also when I try  != it gives me the same result!
            echo $tfilename
            wcn=$(wc -l "$tfullname")
            n=$(expr "$wcn" : '^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)')
            echo "mv -i "${fullname}" "${filename}_files_${n}.${extension}""  
        fi
    done
done
```

Here is the output, independent of the expression in the if statement:

```
text1
mv -i text1.out.bz2 text1_files_3.out.bz2
text2
mv -i text1.out.bz2 text1_files_7.out.bz2
text3
mv -i text1.out.bz2 text1_files_8.out.bz2
text1
mv -i text2.out.bz2 text2_files_3.out.bz2
text2
mv -i text2.out.bz2 text2_files_7.out.bz2
text3
mv -i text2.out.bz2 text2_files_8.out.bz2
text1
mv -i text3.out.bz2 text3_files_3.out.bz2
text2
mv -i text3.out.bz2 text3_files_7.out.bz2
text3
mv -i text3.out.bz2 text3_files_8.out.bz2
```

And here would be the desired output:

```
text1
mv -i text1.out.bz2 text1_files_3.out.bz2
text2
mv -i text2.out.bz2 text2_files_7.out.bz2
text3
mv -i text3.out.bz2 text3_files_8.out.bz2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe spaces matter, change `$filename==$tfilename` to `$filename == $tfilename`.

Comment: And `==` isn't guaranteed to work either. A corrected version of this statement would be `[ "$filename" = "$tfilename" ]`, with the quotes -- `=` is the only string comparison operator in [the POSIX spec for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: Check your script at [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net)

Comment: @Jonny Henly Indeed, That was the issue! Thanks a lot!

Comment: (if it *looks* like it works without the quotes, then you aren't testing with interesting enough filenames -- try creating some with spaces. And if `==` as opposed to `=` is working, then you're using a shell with non-standard-mandated extensions, but your code will break if run on a baseline implementation).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried your solutions as well, with quotes, without, with == and with =, all of them work! Seems like it was all about the spaces.

Comment: @user4050567, as I said, they only all work if your data and environment are insufficiently interesting. Tests without the quotes **will** fail if you create and test with filenames containing spaces. Tests using `==` as an operator **will** fail if you test with a shell that doesn't support it (such as busybox dash).

Comment: @user4050567, ...I'm making that point to make it clear that shell has hidden gotchas and pitfalls -- it's thus important to use tools such as http://shellcheck/, rather than trusting that because something works for you when you test it it'll always work. (On which point -- see [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)).

Comment: @codeforester & CharlesDuffy, just tried shellcheck, amazing tool, didn't know about it before, thanks a lot!